# Error: The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android

I've downloaded sources from blog.kerul.net. After many errors my program starts, but when I'm trying to start program on emulator it gives me this error:

> The application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again

Here is my manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.kerul.mdictionary"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.2" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:maxSdkVersion="13"/><application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Переводчик">
        <activity android:name=".kamusmm" android:label="mDictionary">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".a2m" android:label="a2m" />
        <activity android:name=".m2a" android:label="m2a" />
        <activity android:name=".e2ma" android:label="e2ma" />
        <activity android:name=".aboutus" android:label="about" />
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
          
    </application>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />

</manifest>
```

Here's my Java file:

```
package com.kerul.kamusmm;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class kamusmm extends TabActivity {
    protected TabHost tabHost;
    protected MyDBHelper myDBHelper;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        
        //set tab for dictionaries
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        //setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"dejavusans.ttf"));
        String internetneeded="This app requires Internet connection to download image and pronunciation.";
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), internetneeded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newTabIntent("Melayu", null, m2a.class);
        //newTabIntent(ArabicUtilities.reshape("\u1575\u1604\u1593\u1585\u1576\u1610\u1577"), null, a2m.class);//&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;
        newTabIntent("Arab", null, a2m.class);
        newTabIntent("English", null, e2ma.class);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 
        
    }

    protected void newTabIntent(String label, Drawable icon, Class<?> pageClass) {
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(label);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(label, icon);
        //tabSpec.set
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, pageClass));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
}
```

here is end of my log cat

```
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.kerul.mdictionary/net.kerul.mdictionary.m2a}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:676)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:345)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:235)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at net.kerul.mdictionary.kamusmm.newTabIntent(kamusmm.java:47)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at net.kerul.mdictionary.kamusmm.onCreate(kamusmm.java:34)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  ... 11 more
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at net.kerul.mdictionary.m2a.onCreate(m2a.java:50)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  ... 22 more
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.kerul.mdictionary-2.apk]
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:542)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671)
    04-29 08:36:08.079: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  ... 33 more
    04-29 08:36:08.109: W/ActivityManager(82):   Force finishing activity net.kerul.mdictionary/.kamusmm
    04-29 08:36:08.258: D/dalvikvm(82): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 23% free 9200K/11911K, paused 70ms
    04-29 08:36:08.629: W/ActivityManager(82): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{407f4cb8 net.kerul.mdictionary/.kamusmm}
    04-29 08:36:09.198: D/dalvikvm(148): GC_EXPLICIT freed 155K, 6% free 9060K/9543K, paused 157ms+3ms
    04-29 08:36:09.989: I/Process(379): Sending signal. PID: 379 SIG: 9
    04-29 08:36:10.008: I/ActivityManager(82): Process net.kerul.mdictionary (pid 379) has died.
    04-29 08:36:10.098: W/InputManagerService(82): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407f2fc8
    04-29 08:36:10.979: W/NotificationService(82): Object died trying to hide notification android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@40642888 in package net.kerul.mdictionary
    04-29 08:36:10.979: W/ActivityManager(82): setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 379
    04-29 08:36:11.508: D/dalvikvm(82): GC_CONCURRENT freed 157K, 19% free 9715K/11911K, paused 6ms+5ms
    04-29 08:36:19.419: W/ActivityManager(82): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{407f4cb8 net.kerul.mdictionary/.kamusmm}
```

Comment: post your logcat, so we can see where is your error code.

Comment: @shylendra Its a Console not logcat. Post your logcat here.

Comment: @shylendra its A console, not  a logcat.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA GuPtA wait a minute

Comment: @taxa1991 is this what the logcat said when you run your apps? because if I'm not wrong, this is not logcat error.

Comment: @NenMa how to enable LogCat?

Comment: @NenMa https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/tiwr54xyj/

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA please help me dude http://postimg.org/image/tiwr54xyj/

Comment: @taxa1991 windows-showview-Logcat, and when your application eror, you'll see on red line, that's error log from your apps.

Comment: @NenMa i've posted logcat help dude

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Posted logcat help me

Comment: Problem because you didn't add admob jar file in your libs folder may be.

Answer (score 1):

You got `ClassNotFoundException`

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in
>   loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.kerul.mdictionary-2.apk]

i think you added third party libraries try to  clean your project and build it again.